# Angular 9 production build doesn't create named chunk file

Tags: angular, angular9, ng-build

I tried to build the angular application in production with the chunk name as the module name.

In angular 7 i have set namedChunks: true which build the projects with named chunks like below image

[image]

I tried the same in angular 9 but instead of the named chunks i am getting the chunk files like below image

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Specify `--outputHashing=none` in your `ng build --prod` command. Also make sure that `--namedChunks=true`.